# trouble connecting to featured templates and themes

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, microsoft-office, templates

I have same problem on two computers.  Office 2013 on Windows 10 Pro and Office 2010 on Windows 7 Pro.  I get the message "Sorry, we had some trouble connecting to get featured templates and themes and can't show them right now".
Try again
Work offline

I can work if I choose "Work offline" but have never had to do this selection before.  Try again will not correct the problem.  Is there something from the last updates that changed the Office access?

Comment: You are aware that Office 2010 reach it's end of support in October 2020?  I would not be shocked, that the online functionality not working, isn't intentional since the products are out of support.  Since Office 2013 is technically still support, I would look at your internet configuration, specifically alter any proxy configuration to allow Office access to the internet.

Comment: This appears to be a TLS issue [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/-we-had-trouble-getting-the-featured-templates-and-can-t-show-them-right-now-error-in-office-365-and-pro-plus-2016-da070a0f-e625-8d4a-d0e7-f98be99ac887) is the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The link to your fix is for windows 7 and server 2012 OS not windows 10. My registry on my windows 10 does not have anything past protocols.I have attached screen image of registry[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04gZb.jpg)

Comment: Please also locate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings` check whether there is the "**SecureProtocols**" with the data `0x00000a80`.